# Python error: object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to coding -- taking a Python college course. I know this will be obvious to many of you, but I can not figure out why I continue to get this error attribute error:

```
prodworker = employee.ProductionWorker(shift_num, pay_rate)
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'ProductionWorker'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
class Employee: #writing new class called Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, number): #accepts arguments for employee name and 
        self.__name = name              #employee number 
        self.__number = number

    def set_name(self, name): #mutator methods to set name and number
    self.__name = name



 def set_number(self, number):
        self.__number = number


#accessor methods returns name and number
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number



class ProductionWorker(Employee): #write subclass



    def __init__(self, shift_num, pay_rate):
        Employee.__init__(self, 'ProductionWorker')
        self.__shift_num = shift_num
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate

    def set_shift_num(self, shift_num):
        self.__shift_num = shift_num

    def set_pay_rate(self, pay_rate):
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate     

    def get_shift_num(self):
        return self.__shift_num

    def get_pay_rate(self):
        return self.__pay_rate



#This program creates an instance of Employee Class
#and an instance of Production Worker Class:

again = 'Y'
while again.upper() == 'Y':
    print('Enter the following data for the employee: \n')
    name = input('What is the employee name?: ')
    number = input('What is the employee number? ')


    shift_num = input('What is the employee shift number? 1 = Day, 2 = Night :') 
    while shift_num != '1' and shift_num != '2':
        shift_num = input('Invalid entry! Enter 1 for Day shift or 2 for Night shift!')
    else:
        if shift_num == '1':
            shift_num = 'Day'
        if shift_num == '2':
            shift_num = 'Night'

    pay_rate = float(input('What is the employee pay rate? '))

    print()
    print('This is an instance of the Employee class:') 
    employee = Employee(name, number)   
    print('EMPLOYEE: \t\t'+ employee.get_name())
    print('EMPLOYEE NUMBER: \t' + employee.get_number())
    print()

    print('This is an instance of the Production Worker class: ')
    prodworker = employee.ProductionWorker(shift_num, pay_rate)

    print('SHIFT: \t\t\t' + ProductionWorker.get_shift_num())
    print('PAY RATE: \t\t$' + format(ProductionWorker.get_pay_rate(), ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('--------------------------------------------')

    again = input('Enter Y to add another: ')
    if again.upper() != 'Y':
        print('Program End')
```

Comment: Why do you think `employee` should have an attribute called `ProductionWorker`? It clearly doesn't. An object will, generally speaking, only have those attributes explicitly assigned to it, such as in a method of that object's class (via `self`) or that are methods or attributes of the object's class. At no point do you assign an attribute of `Employee` called `ProductionWorker`

Answer (score 1):

The `ProductionWorker` class is a subclass of the `Employee` class, but that doesn't mean you can call it through an instance of `Employee`. It's still a top-level class that you should call directly. Try replacing `employee.ProductionWorker(...)` with just `ProductionWorker(...)`.

You'll get past the current error, but you may have new ones. For instance, I think the current attempt to call `Employee.__init__` from `ProductionWorker.__init__` will fail because it doesn't pass the right number of arguments. You may also have logic issues, if you expected `employee.ProductionWorker` to create a `ProductionWorker` instance that was related in some way to the `employee` object.

I'd also discourage you from using `__double_leading_underscore` names for your attributes. That invokes Python's name mangling system, which is mostly intended to help prevent *accidental* reuse of the same name from different classes in a large or unpredictable inheritance hierarchy. If you just want your attributes to be "private", use a single underscore. That doesn't protect them from being accessed by outside code, but it serves as documentation that they're not part of the object's public API. One of Python's design philosophies is that it's programmers are responsible for their own behavior (often described with the phrase "We're all consenting adults"). If a programmer wants to access an object's private data they can do so (which can be very useful for debugging). But if they break stuff, they have no one to blame but themselves.

Comment: Thank you Blckknght! I clearly have a lot to learn. There are not many people in my area that know Python, so finding help can be tricky. Thank you!